# How to resize SVG to fill its container?

Tags: reactjs, svg

How can I set my SVGs so that they fill their containing div *without stretching*?
I would like my hexagons as big as possible but no bigger than their grey-colored containing divs, and I want to keep the original aspect ratio.
I am looking for a responsive approach, that would work in both the horizontal and vertical case without hardcoding width and height.

[image]

The code:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#ddd", height: 200 }}>
        <MySvg width="20%" />
      </div>
      <br />
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#ddd", height: 300, width: 200 }}>
        <MySvg width="80%" />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

function MySvg(props) {
  return (
    <svg
      //width="31.921mm"
      //height="36.45mm"
      version="1.1"
      viewBox="0 0 31.921 36.45"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      {...props}
    >
      <g transform="translate(-20.655 -17.456)">
        <path
          d="m51.254 44.131-14.638 8.451-14.638-8.451v-16.902l14.638-8.451 14.638 8.451z"
          fill="none"
          stroke="#fb00ff"
          stroke-linejoin="round"
          stroke-width="2.6458"
        />
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit elastic-rhodes-kecis]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you needed! It will change based on the previous div style!

```
svg {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the proposition, but it does not work with the vertical container (you can try in the code sandbox). It seems that width has priority over height.

Comment: In that case, won't the height be too stretched? You need that kind of style?

Comment: Good point: I would like the image to be as big as possible *without stretching*: it should be as wide or as high as its container depending on the case. I will edit my question to be more specific.

Comment: Yeah exactly, it can't exceed beyond container!

Comment: Actually your solution works! My bad, I must have tripped on the blanket when I tested it! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`style="width: 100%; height: 100%;` with `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"` (default) or other value to align content of SVG element should meet your requirements. MDN: [preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio).

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left
}
```

```html
<script>
  var SVG = `
<svg
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" 
      preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
      version="1.1"
      viewBox="0 0 31.921 36.45"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <g transform="translate(-20.655 -17.456)">
        <path
          d="m51.254 44.131-14.638 8.451-14.638-8.451v-16.902l14.638-8.451 14.638 8.451z"
          fill="none"
          stroke="#fb00ff"
          stroke-linejoin="round"
          stroke-width="2.6458"
        />
      </g>
    </svg>`
</script>

<div style="width: 100px; height: 50px;">
  <script>
    document.write(SVG);
  </script>
</div>


<div style="width: 50px; height: 100px; ">
  <script>
    document.write(SVG);
  </script>
</div>

<div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; ">
  <script>
    document.write(SVG);
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know about preserveAspectRatio, it brings control that I thought was (unfairly) reserved to background image! I accept @Veno's answer because it is more straightforward, as ```preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"``` is the default value.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one way to do it, but it does not feel optimal: I wrap the SVG in a component that compares its aspect ratio to the SVG's aspect ratio and then sets the width and height of the SVG accordingly:

```
function SvgWrapper({ render, aspect }) {
  const containerRef = React.useRef(null);

  const [containerAspect, setContainerAspect] = React.useState(1);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (containerRef.current) {
      const rect = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      setContainerAspect(rect.width / rect.height);
    }
  }, []);

  const width = containerAspect < aspect ? "100%" : "auto";
  const height = containerAspect < aspect ? "auto" : "100%";

  return (
    <div
      ref={containerRef}
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", padding: 0, margin: 0 }}
    >
      {render({ width, height })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then it can be used like this:

```
<div style={{ backgroundColor: "#ddd", width: 200, height: 300 }}>
  <SvgWrapper
    render={(props) => <MySvg {...props} />}
    aspect={31.921 / 36.45}
  />
</div>
```

This solution seems too verbose and requires setting the SVG aspect ratio manually, so if anyone has a better idea, please share!